# ASP.NET How can I initialize a new table made in Identity C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity

Hello guys I was wondering how to initialize some tables that were made in identity  , I've implemented a security module with permissions that belong to a certain role , so I had to add a Permission and RolePermission tables   and  I couldn't find the way how to itialilize them here's  my code where I add the classes that allow to create the Permission and the RolePermission tables  in identity

```
namespace SSMX.Mantra.WebApi.Infrastructure
{
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte Level { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RolePermission> RolePermissions { get; set; }

    //Rest of code is removed for brevity
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> 
    GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string 
    authenticationType)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, 
        authenticationType);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class Permission
{

       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Code { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class RolePermission
{
    [Key]
    public int IdRolePermission { get; set; }
    public int IdPermission { get; set; }
    public int IdRole { get; set; }

    public virtual Permission Permission { get; set; }
    public virtual IdentityRole Role { get; set; }

}
}
```

And here's my code that initialize User and Role tables in the seed method so I tried to do the same as the User and Role tables by implementing  a PermissionManager but I couldn't I would apratiate any help thank you guys.

```
 internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SSMX.Mantra.WebApi.Infrastructure.ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {

            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

            var user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = "SuperPowerUser",
                Email = "taiseer.joudeh@gmail.com",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                FirstName = "Taiseer",
                LastName = "Joudeh",
                Level = 1,
                JoinDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3)
            };

            manager.Create(user, "MySuperP@ss!");

            if (roleManager.Roles.Count() == 0)
            {
                roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole { Name = "SuperAdmin" });
                roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin" });
                roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole { Name = "User" });
            }

            var adminUser = manager.FindByName("SuperPowerUser");

            manager.AddToRoles(adminUser.Id, new string[] { "SuperAdmin", "Admin" });

            var permissions = new List<Permission>
            {
                new Permission()
                {
                    Id = 1, Code = "101", Description = "Competencias.CentroDeportivo.Consulta"
                },
                new Permission()
                {
                    Id = 1, Code = "102", Description = "Competencias.CentroDeportivo.Eliminar"
                },
                new Permission()
                {
                    Id = 1, Code = "102", Description = "Competencias.CentroDeportivo.Crear"
                }

            };

        }
    }
```

Comment: If you tried to implement a permission manager, please post the code that you have already,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add all classes as virtual properties in the IdentityDbContext class, that is inherited from the DbContext
in the Configuration class you showed above, set

```
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
```

then in the Package Manager console run the migration command

```
update-database -verbose
```

Comment: Thanks for  your answer was so useful